# animated sidebar closing issue

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to js. When I click on my menu image it changes to close image but it is not sliding the whole menu it just stuck there. In short when I click it goes to else and executes  `menu.src = "img/close.png"` how to fix it?

my js code:

```
    let menuButton = document.querySelector("#menuButton");
        let side = document.querySelector("#sideNav");
        let menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

        //side.style.width = "-250px"

        menuButton.onclick = function(){ 
            
            if(side.style.right == "-250px"){
                side.style.right = "0px"
               menu.src = "img/close.png"
               
        } else{
            side.style.right == "0px";
            menu.src = "img/close.png"
        }
         }
```

My css code

```
#sideNav{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    right: -250px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #009688;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: .5s;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 50px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#menuButton{
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #009688 ;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
#menuButton img{
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: your if / elese doint exacly the same thing. and you use == in assigment.

Comment: just add new class --expanded and toggle this class. that is cleaner

Comment: @robert thankyou problem was  == in else condition. now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let menuButton = document.querySelector("#menuButton");
        let side = document.querySelector("#sideNav");
        let menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

        menuButton.addEventListener("click",() => { 
            side.classList.toogle(".nav--expanded")
        })
```

```css
#sideNav{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    right: -250px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #009688;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: .5s;
}

#sideNav.nav--expanded{
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s look at what happens when you click

```
if(side.style.right == "-250px"){ // if the menu is already out of view
            side.style.right = "0px" //bring it into view - OK
           menu.src = "img/close.png" // show a close button - OK
           
    } else{ // otherwise the menu is already in view
        side.style.right == "0px"; // so we need to put it out if view, Not keep it where it is - Not OK
        menu.src = "img/close.png" // an we probably want to show a menu img here, not the close one since it’s going to be closed by now - not OK
    }
```